# Hide one monitor from OS X screencapture

Tags: macos, screen-capture

I would like to know how to configure OS X to hide one display while doing automatic screenshots.I have two displays and don't one display to be captured by automatic screencapture.I don't want to use any thridparty apps, I want to configure screencapture in the way that if some app will do screencapture - One display will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in program called Grab.

[image: Grab]

From the top menu select capture->Screen or hit CMD+Z [image: Screen]

Another solution is to run it from terminal "screencapture". There are many options. Some of them you can write to user defaults:
[image: Terminal]

Comment: I have a thirdparty program that is doing screenshot - So I think I need some predefined options.

Comment: Are you sure that 3rd party s using screencapture to grab screen? If yes create symlink to screencapture. So screencapture command will resolve as "screencapture -m" where m is the main monitor. You don't have more options then those that you see in the terminal output.

Comment: Could you help with that ?
I need to do somethin like that ? 
sudo ln -s /usr/sbin/screencapture '/usr/sbin/screencapture -m'

Comment: It's called alias but I am not exactly sure if it works outside of terminal  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33204/how-to-make-a-symbolic-link-to-usr-bin-vim-but-with-start-up-parameters Or contact the person from 3rd party and ask him how to do it the way you want